# How to convert [numpy.ndarray of ndarrays] to one ndarray of numbers

Tags: python, numpy, numpy-ndarray

I somehow got the following type of weird-looking, nested numpy array. I wonder if there's some way to convert it to a normal one (without all these 'array' in the output).

```py
features
> array([array([1, 0]), array([2, 0]), array([3, 0]), array([4, 0]),
       array([5, 0]), array([6, 0]), array([7, 0]), array([8, 0]),
       array([9, 0])], dtype=object)

features.reshape((9,1))
> array([[array([1, 0])],
       [array([2, 0])],
       [array([3, 0])],
       [array([4, 0])],
       [array([5, 0])],
       [array([6, 0])],
       [array([7, 0])],
       [array([8, 0])],
       [array([9, 0])]], dtype=object)

features.flatten()
> array([array([1, 0]), array([2, 0]), array([3, 0]), array([4, 0]),
       array([5, 0]), array([6, 0]), array([7, 0]), array([8, 0]),
       array([9, 0])], dtype=object)

features.squeeze()
> array([array([1, 0]), array([2, 0]), array([3, 0]), array([4, 0]),
       array([5, 0]), array([6, 0]), array([7, 0]), array([8, 0]),
       array([9, 0])], dtype=object)

features.reshape((-1,2))
> ValueError: cannot reshape array of size 9 into shape (2)
```

This issue matters because it messes with the shape of the array. For example,

```py
features.shape
> (9,)
```

while it should really be `(9,2)`.

I really appreciate your help.

**Desired Output:**

```
features
> array([[1, 0],
       [2, 0],
       [3, 0],
       [4, 0],
       [5, 0],
       [6, 0],
       [7, 0],
       [8, 0],
       [9, 0]], dtype=int32)

features.ndim
> 2

features.shape
> (9,2)
```

Update:
@MaxNoe's comment pointed out my mistake that the array wasn't rectangular. However, after I corrected the mistake via debug terminal, I still cannot easily convert the array to dtype=int32. It seems that once numpy recognizes ndarray as object there's hardly a way back to treat it as numbers.

My interest is whether there's an easy way to make the conversion. If not, I'd better edit my code to avoid the situation from occurring.

To ensure that we have the same thing, you can run

```
import pickle
features = pickle.loads(b'\x80\x03cnumpy.core.multiarray\n_reconstruct\nq\x00cnumpy\nndarray\nq\x01K\x00\x85q\x02C\x01bq\x03\x87q\x04Rq\x05(K\x01K\x04K\x02\x86q\x06cnumpy\ndtype\nq\x07X\x02\x00\x00\x00O8q\x08K\x00K\x01\x87q\tRq\n(K\x03X\x01\x00\x00\x00|q\x0bNNNJ\xff\xff\xff\xffJ\xff\xff\xff\xffK?tq\x0cb\x89]q\r(h\x00h\x01K\x00\x85q\x0eh\x03\x87q\x0fRq\x10(K\x01K\x02\x85q\x11h\x07X\x02\x00\x00\x00i4q\x12K\x00K\x01\x87q\x13Rq\x14(K\x03X\x01\x00\x00\x00<q\x15NNNJ\xff\xff\xff\xffJ\xff\xff\xff\xffK\x00tq\x16b\x89C\x08\x01\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00q\x17tq\x18bh\x00h\x01K\x00\x85q\x19h\x03\x87q\x1aRq\x1b(K\x01K\x02\x85q\x1ch\x14\x89C\x08\x02\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00q\x1dtq\x1ebh\x00h\x01K\x00\x85q\x1fh\x03\x87q Rq!(K\x01K\x02\x85q"h\x14\x89C\x08\x03\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00q#tq$bh\x00h\x01K\x00\x85q%h\x03\x87q&Rq\'(K\x01K\x02\x85q(h\x14\x89C\x08\x04\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00q)tq*bh\x00h\x01K\x00\x85q+h\x03\x87q,Rq-(K\x01K\x02\x85q.h\x14\x89C\x08\x05\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00q/tq0bh\x00h\x01K\x00\x85q1h\x03\x87q2Rq3(K\x01K\x02\x85q4h\x14\x89C\x08\x06\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00q5tq6bh\x00h\x01K\x00\x85q7h\x03\x87q8Rq9(K\x01K\x02\x85q:h\x14\x89C\x08\x08\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00q;tq<bh\x00h\x01K\x00\x85q=h\x03\x87q>Rq?(K\x01K\x02\x85q@h\x14\x89C\x08\t\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00qAtqBbetqCb.')
```

Comment: can you share the desired output? what is a normal one?

Comment: Numpy arrays need to be rectangular. Your last item only has a single entry, so this array of arrays cannot be a single  ndarray

Comment: "However, after I corrected the mistake via debug terminal" - fix the code at the location the problem originally occurred, and you should get a normal array. Don't try to fix it in postprocessing.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I can recreate your array with:

```
In [126]: array=np.array                                                                               
In [127]: alist = [array([1, 0]), array([2, 0]), array([3, 0]), array([4, 0]), 
     ...:        array([5, 0]), array([6, 0]), array([7, 0]), array([8, 0]), 
     ...:        array([9, 0])]                                                                        
In [128]: len(alist)                                                                                   
Out[128]: 9
In [129]: arr = np.empty(9, dtype=object)                                                              
In [130]: arr[:]=alist                                                                                 
In [131]: arr                                                                                          
Out[131]: 
array([array([1, 0]), array([2, 0]), array([3, 0]), array([4, 0]),
       array([5, 0]), array([6, 0]), array([7, 0]), array([8, 0]),
       array([9, 0])], dtype=object)
```

`np.stack` is a good way of joining the arrays into one.  `np.vstack` would also work.

```
In [132]: np.stack(arr)                                                                                
Out[132]: 
array([[1, 0],
       [2, 0],
       [3, 0],
       [4, 0],
       [5, 0],
       [6, 0],
       [7, 0],
       [8, 0],
       [9, 0]])
```

The reason I didn't simply copy-n-paste your original array is that it would skip the object dtype:

```
In [133]: np.array(alist)                                                                              
Out[133]: 
array([[1, 0],
       [2, 0],
       [3, 0],
       [4, 0],
       [5, 0],
       [6, 0],
       [7, 0],
       [8, 0],
       [9, 0]])
```

`reshape`, `flattened` etc do nothing because the object dtype shape is (9,), not anything that can be reshape into a (9,2).  You have to take the object dtype seriously!

Comment: Thank you so much! np.stack() perfectly worked for my situation. As you said, I should really be careful about the object dtype.

Answer (score 0):

as easy as that:

```
features = np.array([np.array([1, 0]), np.array([2, 0]), np.array([3, 0]), np.array([4, 0]),
   np.array([5, 0]), np.array([6, 0]), np.array([7, 0]), np.array([8, 0]),
   np.array([9, 0])], dtype=object)

features = np.reshape(features, (-1, 2)).astype('Int32')
print(features)
# output 
[[1 0]
 [2 0]
 [3 0]
 [4 0]
 [5 0]
 [6 0]
 [7 0]
 [8 0]
 [9 0]]

print(features.dtype) # int32
print(features.ndim)  # 2 
print(features.shape) # (9, 2)
```

Comment: @XiaoyuLiu  okay didnt notice you want to convert your array to int type. would that solve your problem?

Comment: strange. I still get ValueError: cannot reshape array of size 9 into shape (2). Maybe there's something strange about my specific object... I don't know. @Mercury's list solution worked so I think I'm accepting him/her. Thank you anyway!

Comment: @XiaoyuLiu I just want to ask if you are copying the code or writing it yourself?

Comment: I don't know exactly what you mean. As for the code in my question, I copied from debug console. As for testing your code, I entered it myself into the debug console and observed the output.

Answer (score 0):

One solution would be to use tolist and then convert back.

```
np.array(features.tolist(),dtype=np.int32)
```

I can only create your array in a weird way:

```
features = np.array([np.array([1, 0]), np.array([2, 0]), np.array([3, 0]), np.array([4, 0]),
                     np.array([5, 0]), np.array([6, 0]), np.array([7, 0]), np.array([8, 0]),
                     np.array([9])], dtype=object)
features[-1] = np.array([9,0])

>>>features

   array([array([1, 0]),
          array([2, 0]), array([3, 0]),
          array([4, 0]),
          array([5, 0]),
          array([6, 0]),
          array([7, 0]),
          array([8, 0]),
          array([9, 0])], dtype=object)

features = np.array(features.tolist(),dtype=np.int32)

>>>features
array([[1, 0],
       [2, 0],
       [3, 0],
       [4, 0],
       [5, 0],
       [6, 0],
       [7, 0],
       [8, 0],
       [9, 0]], dtype=int32)
```

Comment: It worked very well. Since @hpaulj suggested np.stack which is more elegant, I'm probably accepting his answer. Thank you very much for your useful answer!

Comment: You're welcome! And hpaulj's right, stack is certainly the way to go here.